# Want to customize Jump logic of Typeform

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, typeform

Can anyone help me in finding out a way to customize jump logic in the forms provided by Typeform.com?

Is that even possible, even by contacting them?

I have a form built using typeform in which email should be checked for existence in my database and accordingly upcoming fields should change. Can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to dynamically check if a mail match one of your users while he's filling the form. However, you can adapt your form depending on wether or not a user in logged in.

basically, your form URL must be something like 
`https://[yourName].typeform.com/to/[yourFormId]`

In your application, you can set some kinf of logic to modify the URL of your form if the user is logged in

```
https://[yourName].typeform.com/to/[yourFormId]<%= current_user? "?mail="+current_user.email : "" %>
```

If user is logged in, a hidden field will be sent to your form. You can retrieve it from your form dashboard and do any logic jump you want (like, `if mail is not "", do stuff`)

If user is not logged in, it will start the form from the beginning.